# How to parse a haskell unicode string into unicode character

Tags: haskell

I have a `String` representing a unicode character in Haskell, say `"\\x00a0"` and I want to convert it into `Char` ('\x00a0' in this case).

My last failed attempt is to `read` it as Int, then use `Data.Char.chr` to convert back to `Char`. It works for octal literals `"\\xxx"` but not on Unicode.

Can someone give me pointers on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Data.Char` contains [`readLitChar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Char.html#v:readLitChar), which will work on any Haskell string escape sequence (except for gaps and separators, of course):

```
Prelude Data.Char> readLitChar "\\x00a0"
[('\160',"")]
```